# What is the limit of this function as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let the function $f \colon (\mathbf{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \colon x+y = 0 \}) \to \mathbf{R}$ be defined as follows: 
$$ f(x,y) \colon= \frac{xy}{x+y}$$ if $(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2$ and  $x+y \ne 0$.

Then what is the value of $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)?$$

Using the iterated limits, we obtain 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y) ) = \lim_{x \to 0} (\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{xy}{x+y} ) = \lim_{x\to 0} 0 = 0,$$ and also 
$$\lim_{y\to 0} (\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y) ) = \lim_{y \to 0} (\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{xy}{x+y} ) = \lim_{y\to 0} 0 = 0.$$ However, the equality of these two iterated limits is only necessary, and not sufficient, for the existence of my desired limit.

What is the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ if we define $f$ as follows? 
$$ f(x,y) \colon= \frac{xy}{x+y}$$ if $x+y \ne 0$, and 
$$ f(x,y) \colon= 0$$ if $x+y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x^2-x$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(x^2-x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3-x^2}{x^2}=0-1=-1$$
which is not equal to the limit along the axes, thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks.